# facebook login for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In one of the website I need login with facebook account. I am using following code on face book login button.

```
string callbackUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/" +
          "authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope=offline_access," +
          "publish_stream,read_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages",
          1448xxxxxx781763, callbackUrl));
```

it shows 'Success' with access token url for a brief moment and then a security message appears and the access token is lost. How can I capture the access token? Thanks

[image: First screen with code]

[image: Second screen with warning message]

Answer (score 0):

Use your own domain for the callbackURL, not facebook.com.

That being said, you are better off by using the JavaScript SDK for login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0

That way you don´t have to worry about the Access Token at all.

Comment: This is mentioned in facebook docs that this url is a must. I tried using my own url but the output gives an error.

Comment: i know that the url is required, but redirecting to facebook.com is wrong - of course you don´t get the access token if it redirects to a page you don´t own.

Comment: what error do you get? i assume you did not set the app settings correct. make sure the app domain is set to your domain.

Comment: I tried putting several domains there including localhost but its not working. I get domain do not have permissions errorr2

Comment: ...and you added the correct platform in the settings? (website) - the error does sound like you got the domain wrong though.